# ngx-slider in angular triggers unwantedly when scrolling on mobile

Tags: angular, typescript, slider

So I'm working on a survey app that implements ngx-sliders. The issue arises on mobile, where people scroll down rows of slider questions they inadvertently trigger the slider when scrolling, changing the answers.

I've tried disabling it on (touchmove) event, which it does, but only AFTER changing the slider value. Disabling it on (touchstart) doesn't work. I tried the touchEventsInterval slider option, didn't work. Tried event.preventDefault() as well. No cigar.
Right now I'm trying to access it with ElementRef. I could technically have the slider on readonly, somehow register a click and where it was placed, then change the class of that particular tick as active, but I'm really struggling with implementing this. I'm not really sure if this is a good idea/feasible.

I'm really running out of ideas here

This is the html

```
<div class="slider-field hide-value-ticks mb-5">
  <div class="subtitle-black mb-4">{{answer.rowAnswerText ?? ''}} {{answer.columnAnswerText}}</div>
      <ngx-slider 
      *ngIf="options" 
      class="touch-slider" 
      [value]="selectedAnswer" 
      (valueChange)="sliderValueChange($event)" 
      [options]="options"
      (click)="onClick($event)
      #sliderNgx
      ></ngx-slider>
</div>
```

And the .ts

```
export class PathfinderStepSliderComponent implements OnInit {

  rating: { value: string; label: string }[];
  @Input('rating') set setRating(rating: { value: string; label: string }[]) {
    if (rating == null) {
      return;
    }
    this.rating = rating;

    const options: Options = {
      showTicks: true,
      stepsArray: [],
      disabled: false
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < rating.length; i++) {
      options.stepsArray?.push({value: i, legend: rating[i].label});
    }
    this.options = options;
  }

  answer: SurveyQuestionAnswerModel;
  @Input('answer') set setAnswer(answer: SurveyQuestionAnswerModel) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.selectedAnswer = undefined;
  }

  selectedAnswer: number | undefined;
  @Input('selectedAnswer') set setSelectedAnswer(answer: string) {
    this.selectedAnswer = this.rating.findIndex(r => r.value === answer);
  }
  @Output() selectedAnswerChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @ViewChild('sliderNgx', {static: true}) sliderNgx: ElementRef;

  options: Options;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  sliderValueChange(value: number) {
    this.selectedAnswerChange.emit(this.rating[value].value); 
  }



  onClick(event) {
    const slider = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('ngx-slider');
    console.log(event);
    console.log('slider');
    console.log(slider);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, I solved my problem with this. I set the readonly slider option to true and added a click listener:

```
onSelectAnswer(e, slider) {
    // there was a bug, when you clicked on the blank space between the ticks, the index would be set to 2 (middle of slider)
    const ignoreTargetClassName = 'ngx-slider-span ngx-slider-bar';
    
    const sliderElements = [...(slider.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(e.target.className) as any)];
    
    const index = sliderElements.findIndex(elem => elem === e.target);
    
    if (index !== -1 && (e.target.className !== ignoreTargetClassName)) {
      this.selectedAnswer = index;
    }
  }
```

ANd the html file:

```
<div class="slider-field hide-value-ticks mb-5">
  <div class="subtitle-black mb-4">{{answer.rowAnswerText ?? ''}} {{answer.columnAnswerText}}</div>
    <ngx-slider 
    id="slider"
    *ngIf="options" 
    class="touch-slider" 
    [value]="selectedAnswer" 
    (valueChange)="sliderValueChange($event)" 
    [options]="options"
    (click)="onSelectAnswer($event, ngxSlider)"
    #ngxSlider
    ></ngx-slider>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895997/disable-value-change-on-click-rage-line-angular-material) is to use the CSS `pointer-events` variable.

Set the .ngx-slider class to have `pointer-events: none` and the .ngx-slider-pointer to have `pointer-events: all`.

In my example I needed to use nest these selectors within the `::ng-deep` selector - here's a reference to the [ngx-slider custom-styling guide](https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/blob/master/STYLING.md).

```
/* component.scss */
::ng-deep {
    .ngx-slider {
        /* in my example, I only want mobile and tablets to not respond to touches. Desktop I want to be able to click to a specific value */
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            pointer-events: none;
            .ngx-slider-pointer {
                pointer-events: all;
            }
        }
    }
}
```